# Modification of the basic if expression in Scheme. Why does it go into an infinite loop?

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, infinite-loop, racket

In Scheme, I modified the basic 'if' command as:

```
(define (modified-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
  (if predicate
      then-clause
      else-clause))
```

And then I defined a simple factorial generating program using the modified version of if:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (modified-if (= n 0)
               (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

Now, when I call the above function, it goes into an infinite loop. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scheme has eager evaluation. This means that, unless you're using a special form (like `if`) or a macro (like `cond` or `case`) that delegates to such a special form, *all* subexpressions are evaluated first.

That means for your expression

```
(modified-if (= n 0)
             1
             (* n (factorial (- n 1))))
```

the `(* n (factorial (- n 1)))` is evaluated first, before `modified-if` is run. (It may be run before or after `(= n 0)`, but it doesn't matter either way, the recursive call still happens regardless.) And since this is a recursive call, that means that your program will infinitely recurse, and you will eventually run out of stack.

Here's a simple example: consider this:

```
(if #t
    (display "Yay!")
    (error "Oh noes!"))
```

Because `if` is a special form, and it only evaluates the necessary branch, in this case it will only evaluate `(display "Yay!")` and not evaluate `(error "Oh noes!")`. But if you switch to using your `modified-if`, both expressions will be evaluated, and your program will raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use the stepper in DrRacket to see how your modified-if behaves.

Choose the "Beginner" language. Enter the program below, and then click the stepper icon:

```
(define (modif predicate then-clause else-clause)
  (if predicate then-clause else-clause))
(define (factorial n)
  (modif (= n 0) 1 (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
(factorial 5)
```

You can now step for step see how the computation evolves. Notice that `modif` follows the rule of function application.

For an example of how the DrRacket stepper looks like:
[image]